# ngx Bootstrap Typeahead show all list again after selected and focus again

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have auto selected the data from code

ts.code

```
this.add_resutant_form.patchValue({
    select_company: this.selectedCompany.name
  })
```

HTML

```
        <input 
        [typeahead]="companyList" 
        formControlName="select_company" 
        typeaheadOptionField="name" 
        [typeaheadMinLength]="0" 
        (typeaheadOnSelect)="onSelectCompany($event)" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.select_resturant.errors}">
```

The value in the field is auto selected which is fine but when i again focus on textbox i see only selected one other are hide.

Is it possible to show all if I re-focus again ?

[image]

This [issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3968) is something similar. But I cannot get it working.

[ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead)